# Text content of a div skip the line in adaptive card. - BotFramework

Tags: javascript, html, css, botframework

I'm trying to change the web chat appearance of botframework.
When presenting the adaptive cards they exceed the div:

[image: That's the way it looks when presenting the adaptive cards.]

I would like the text contents that are in the buttons elements with the "ac-pushButton" class to skip a line. To not exceed the div.

Below is the html and css code for adaptive cards:

```css
div {
    display: block;
}


.wc-message-from-bot {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8px; }

.wc-message-from-bot .wc-message-content {
  background-color: #eceff1;
  color: #000000; }

.wc-message-from-bot .wc-message-content {
    background-color: #eceff1;
    color: #000000;
}

/* list */
.wc-list > .wc-card {
  margin-top: 8px; }

.wc-list > .wc-card:first-child {
  margin-top: 0; }

/* alternate chat sizes */
.wc-message {
  max-width: 91%; }

.wc-card {
  border: 1px solid #d2dde5;
  width: 302px; }

.wc-adaptive-card {
  width: 318px; }

.wc-wide .wc-card {
  border: 1px solid #d2dde5;
  width: 398px; }

.wc-wide .wc-adaptive-card {
  width: 414px; }

.wc-narrow .wc-card {
  border: 1px solid #d2dde5;
  width: 198px; }

.wc-narrow .wc-adaptive-card {
  width: 214px; }

/* adaptive card adjustments from wc-card */
.wc-adaptive-card p {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0; }

.wc-message-content {
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 8px;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="wc-list">
    <div class="wc-card wc-adaptive-card hero">
        <div class="ac-container" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); padding: 8px; box-sizing: border-box;">
            <div class="ac-container" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); padding: 0px; box-sizing: border-box;"></div>
            <div style="height: 8px;"></div>
            <div>
                <div style="overflow: hidden;">
                    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start;"><button type="button" class="ac-pushButton" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; flex: 0 1 auto;">O que encontro na p&amp;#225;gina Meu Perfil?</button>
                        <div style="height: 8px;"></div>
                        
                        <button type="button" class="ac-pushButton" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; flex: 0 1 auto;">O que &amp;#233; o Minha Carteira na p&amp;#225;gina Meu Perfil?</button>
                        <div style="height: 8px;"></div><button type="button" class="ac-pushButton" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; flex: 0 1 auto;">O que &amp;#233; Meu Endere&amp;#231;o na p&amp;#225;gina Meu Perfil?</button>
                        <div style="height: 8px;"></div><button type="button" class="ac-pushButton" style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; flex: 0 1 auto;">None of the above.</button></div>
                </div>
                <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I managed to do was leave it like this:

[image: Change width to auto from class wc-adaptive-card]

Sub:Change width to auto from class wc-adaptive-card.

But I'd like him to present the full text.

Note: I am a beginner.

Comment: change style of the button to this: overflow: visible;
    text-overflow: initial;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve here by adding the following:

```
.ac-pushButton {
       white-space: normal;
}
.wc-adaptive-card {
       width: auto; 
}
```

Comment: @StevenG. Only I can accept my answer in two days, right?

Comment: Ah you're right, my mistake! [[self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)]

Answer (score 3):

I believe below approach solves your problem. I removed unnecessary inline styles, which were causing problems, most notably `overflow: hidden`.

Please let me know if it works for you just fine.

```css
.ac-pushButton {
  text-align: left;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

.wc-message-from-bot {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.wc-message-from-bot .wc-message-content {
  background-color: #eceff1;
  color: #000000;
}

.wc-message-from-bot .wc-message-content {
  background-color: #eceff1;
  color: #000000;
}


/* list */

.wc-list>.wc-card {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.wc-list>.wc-card:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/* alternate chat sizes */

.wc-message {
  max-width: 91%;
}

.wc-card {
  border: 1px solid #d2dde5;
  width: 302px;
}

.wc-adaptive-card {
  width: 318px;
}

.wc-wide .wc-card {
  border: 1px solid #d2dde5;
  width: 398px;
}

.wc-wide .wc-adaptive-card {
  width: 414px;
}

.wc-narrow .wc-card {
  border: 1px solid #d2dde5;
  width: 198px;
}

.wc-narrow .wc-adaptive-card {
  width: 214px;
}


/* adaptive card adjustments from wc-card */

.wc-adaptive-card p {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.wc-message-content {
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 8px;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="wc-list">
  <div class="wc-card wc-adaptive-card hero">
    <div class="ac-container" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); padding: 8px; box-sizing: border-box;">
      <div class="ac-container" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); padding: 0px; box-sizing: border-box;"></div>
      <div style="height: 8px;"></div>
      <div>
        <div style="overflow: hidden;">
          <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start;">
            <button type="button" class="ac-pushButton">
            O que encontro na p&amp;#225;gina Meu Perfil?
          </button>
            <div style="height: 8px;"></div>
            <button type="button" class="ac-pushButton">
              O que &amp;#233; o Minha Carteira na p&amp;#225;gina Meu Perfil?</button>
            <div style="height: 8px;">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="ac-pushButton">
              O que &amp;#233; Meu Endere&amp;#231;o na p&amp;#225;gina Meu Perfil?
            </button>
            <div style="height: 8px;">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="ac-pushButton">
              None of the above.
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still has not solved the problem completely.  https://ibb.co/jmS4c8

Comment: I noticed that you just added the style on top of the buttons elements, right ?!

Comment: Yes, I added CSS for buttons. `.ac-pushButton { text-align: left; height: auto; max-width: 100%; }`. That ensures they won't expand over 100% width of parent. Please copy code to your project and check it, because as you can see in snippet it works just fine.

Comment: @RafaelOliveira: please let me know if my solution works for you and if so, mark my answer as accepted, please. :).

Comment: Then I don't know what result are you trying to achieve. If my snippet doesn't show desired result, then please let me know what you are trying to get.

Comment: I was able to resolve here by adding the following:
.ac-pushButton {
       white-space: normal!
     }
     .wc-adaptive-card {
       width: auto
       ; }

Comment: I still don't understand what was your problem and why my solution didn't fix it and would be glad to know. :).